# array declaration in runtime and compile time

Tags: c++, arrays, variable-length-array

Please look at the following 2 program segments:

```
  int a,b; 
  cin>>a>>b;   
  int arr1[a*b];
  int arr2[a];
```

now if i give input value of 'a' = 100000 and 'b' = 5, program shows runtime error because of memory overflow I think. Now look to the other segment of code:

```
  int arr1[500000];
  int arr2[100000];
```

Now when I declare array of same size as shown in above code, The program works fine. Why is that so?

Comment: Variable length arrays are not supported in C++.

Comment: What @haccks said. C-style arrays and `std::array` sizes MUST be known at compile time. You can use `std::vector` or dynamically allocate an array.

Comment: *"program shows runtime error because of memory overflow I think"* - Don't paraphrase the error message. Use copy & paste to add it to the question.

Answer (score 1):

> Now when I declare array in advance of same size I declared at runtime, The program works fine. Why is that so?

Because variable length arrays (aka VLAs) aren't valid standard c++ code.

If you need such thing allocated at runtime the idiomatic c++ way is to use a `std::vector`:

```
int a,b; 
cin>>a>>b;   
std::vector<int> arr1(a*b);
std::vector<int> arr2(a);
```

Comment: I am not using variable size array here. The point is that in both program segment size of both array is same. But first segment shows the error but second segment does not.

Comment: @ShivaVerma _"But first segment shows the error"_ That's a VLA actually, and it's not supported with standard C++.

Comment: *"I am not using variable size array here."* - Yes, you are. You are very likely using g++, which accepts VLAs as an extension. With the correct compiler flags, it will also print a warning message for them. Do what everyone tells you and use `std::vector`.

Comment: @ChristianHackl just curious. What are the "correct compiler flags" ? Using the `-Wall` does not produce any warning for me using `gcc 5.4.0`

Comment: @SebTu Did you try `--pedantic`?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ ok. works : `warning: ISO C++ forbids variable length array ‘arr1’ [-Wvla] : int arr1[a*b];` equal warning for the `arr2` variable..

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ But when I take the value of a and b lesser, lets say a = 10000 and b = 5, Then first segment of code works completely fine.

Comment: @ShivaVerma Go with the `std::vector` and stop bothering with compiler specific extensions.