# for this code I am getting run time error .Abort signal from abort(3) (SIGABRT)'

Tags: c++, runtime-error, abort

```
 #include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void reverse(int A[],int N){
    
    for(int i=0;i<N/2;i++){
        swap(A[i],A[N-i-1]);
    }
        for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
        cout<<A[i];
    }
}

int main() {
    //code
    int T,N,A[N];
    cin>>T>>N;
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
        cin>>A[i];
    }
    reverse(A,N);
    //please help it its getting into my nerves

    return 0;
}
```

please help me resolve this problem
for this code I am getting run time error .Abort signal from abort(3) (SIGABRT)'

Comment: `int T,N,A[N];`... How many elements does `A` have, at its declaration here?

Comment: Always compile with *warnings enabled*, and **do not** accept code until it *compiles without warning*. To enable warnings add `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` to your `gcc/clang` compile string (also consider adding `-Wshadow` to warn on shadowed variables). For **VS** (`cl.exe` on windows), use `/W3`. All other compilers will have similar options. Read and understand each warning -- then go fix it. The warnings will identify any problems, and the exact line on which they occur. You can learn a lot by listening to what your compiler is telling you.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting error because you didn't initialize your variables with default values.

Problem 1: `int T,N,A[N];` here `N` is initialized with garbage value.

Problem 2:  you initialize / declare `A[]` before getting `N` value from the input.

Solution :

```
 int T,N;
 cin>>T>>N;
 int A[N];
```

Side note: There is better and efficient solution using vector given below :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

void reverse(vector<int>& x) {
     reverse(x.begin(), x.end());

  return;
}

int main() 
{
vector<int> list;
int listSize;

cout << "How much element you want to put in list" << endl;
cin >> listSize;

cout << "Enter the numbers :" << endl;
for (int number; cin >> number;) {
        list.push_back(number);
     
     if (list.size() == listSize)
        break;

}

reverse(list);

cout << "The reverse of your numbers : ";
for (const int x : list)
    cout << x <<' ';

cout << endl;

return 0;
```

}

Comment: Standard-array-sizes must be known at compile time. Use a vector instead. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42172969/array-declaration-in-runtime-and-compile-time

Comment: @kometen yes, you are  right.

Comment: You can edit your answer and show a solution using a vector if you want to. :-) Here is an example I found with a vector. https://www.programiz.com/cpp-programming/vectors. Like `int vs = 5; vector <int> my_v(vs, 67);`.

Answer (score 0):

Here the problem is that you are declaring A[N] before any value has been assigned to N. Declare A[N] once you have input the value of N.